# Persist the status of a button after refresh using ajax

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I'm currently running nodejs webserver and I'm trying to preserve the status of a button that changes background color when clicked. I tried local storage but if the webpage is accessed by a different computer(computer2) the state does not reflect which was set previously by computer 1. I understand that it is only stored in the computers' local storage. Can anyone help me how to do this in ajax so that it will be stored in the server and can be retrieved by any computer.

```
<button type="button" class="btn">text</button>
```

```js
<script>
$('.btn').click(function(){
 $(this).css('background-color','red');
});
</script>
```

Comment: You are essentially asking us how to store the data on the server, which is too broad of a question, given the many types of servers available, and many ways of doing it.  It would help if you provided a desired storage medium (such as a specific database) that you wanted to use to do this sort of thing.

Comment: Unless you are using a login authentication there will be no way to know who user is from device to device. Beyond that how to store on server is too broad a question

Comment: In your click function, you would use the Jquery ajax method to POST the value to your Node server. You can write the endpoint manually or use a library such as express.js. That endpoint would write the data to one of the many ways to store data serverside. (SQL, object stores, file, etc). On subsequent page loads, you would make another call to your server to GET the value. Search online for a Node CRUD tutorial.

Comment: I plan to use mongodb. I simple example code would help me greatly and if it help u guys  any database will do as long as it is written in javascript